# Pass data to already running Celery task in Django

Tags: django, redis, celery

I have a Dajngo application that runs Celery task like

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def start_serial_acquisition(self, idObj, porta_COM):
   __cycle_over_something__
```

launched with

```
start_serial_acquisition.delay(instance.pk, porta_COM)
```

Is there a way to, knowing the task id, to send data (i.e. a variable/dicitonary/list) to an already running celery task?

Because the Celery task have to do a certain number of instruction cyclically for a certain number of time, my idea was to use **Redis** with a fixed key, and read on every cycle the key.

The Django application will write on the specific Redis key when needed. The task will do something if the value read from the key is a certain value

This idea is a bit of a workaround as, I would prefer something more *event driven*